# Revolut Business Api failure on transfer and payment endpoints

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to integrate Revolut Business Api into our system. Mainly it will handle only payments to external (non-revolut) accounts.
Working in php and using Laravel.
I’m using the sandbox environment and the authorization process is working well, also checking our own accounts (different currencies) and creating and editing counterparties are working as expected.

During the development I and ran into a problem and I couldnt find any information online or in any community pages.

Any other endpoint (besides the above mentioned) that I’m calling is giving back an error 500 with the following error message

e.g:  {"message":"Oops! An error occurred while processing your request. It has been logged for further investigation. Error Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxx”}

For testing purposes I send it payloads with bad data, and the response is working as expected pointing out the problematic data.

e.g: wrong currency transfer from specific account, or negative figure in the amount field, etc.

But whenever I send in a correct data (I believe it is correct) it responses with the above mentioned 500 error.

I do believe that the problem is on my end and I’m doing something in not the specific way.

Is anyone ran into the same situation?

Thank you
Tamas